# Inquiry about SQL Group By do not group based on first element

Tags: mysql

Here is the sample of the dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CJ2633lwHGURQqK3LzkZUwb-wZwAjg1K/view?usp=sharing

My desire output is  (just a sample to roughly what I want)

| Product_ID | Unit_Sold |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | 3 |
| 202 | 4 |
| 203 | 2 |
| 204 | 2 |

Here is my code running in SSMS

```
SELECT Product_ID, Unit_Sold 
FROM SALES_TRANSACTION 
GROUP BY Product_ID, Unit_Sold
```

But the output does not total all the Unit_Sold by Product_ID (Show partially)

[image: Partial output from SSMS]

Anything missing in my SQL code?

Comment: You want `SUM(Unit_Sold)` to get the totals.

Comment: Or maybe you want `COUNT(*)`. Either way, you need to use an aggregation function to combine the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Product_ID, SUM(Unit_Sold)
FROM SALES_TRANSACTION 
GROUP BY Product_ID, Unit_Sold
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT Product_ID, SUM(Unit_Sold) FROM SALES_TRANSACTION GROUP BY Product_ID;
```